# ESP32 data transfer to C# Web API

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, httpclient, wifi, swagger-ui, arduino-esp32

How can I transfer the data I read from the rfid card with the esp32 card to the C# ASP.NET Core 5 Web API (Swagger interface) to the interface I created via the API? And I want to see my data in Swagger interface (on my own computer and to an API that is not live).

I posted the ESP32 layer to the Web API I prepared using `HttpClient` via wifi, but I did not get any results.